# No package found with specified pattern: d:\a\r1\a\**\*.zip -- Solution

Tags: azure-devops

2019-09-23T14:18:00.9155815Z ##[section]Starting: Deploy Azure App Service
2019-09-23T14:18:00.9273825Z ==============================================================================
2019-09-23T14:18:00.9273966Z Task         : Azure App Service deploy
2019-09-23T14:18:00.9274050Z Description  : Deploy to Azure App Service a web, mobile, or API app using Docker, Java, .NET, .NET Core, Node.js, PHP, Python, or Ruby
2019-09-23T14:18:00.9274142Z Version      : 4.157.0
2019-09-23T14:18:00.9274199Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2019-09-23T14:18:00.9274290Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment
2019-09-23T14:18:00.9274393Z ==============================================================================
2019-09-23T14:18:01.7517839Z Got service connection details for Azure App Service:'devopsPlan'
2019-09-23T14:18:01.9875957Z ##[error]Error: Resource 'devopsPlan' doesn't exist. Resource should exist before deployment.
2019-09-23T14:18:01.9890475Z (node:1644) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): TypeError: Cannot read property 'getApplicationURL' of undefined
2019-09-23T14:18:01.9935959Z ##[section]Finishing: Deploy Azure App Service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add one more task in azure-pipelines.yml file like "- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1" and it solved.

> https://github.com/pomtom/AZ-Devops/blob/master/azure-pipelines.yml

Comment: Hi, very appreciate this answer shared here. You can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) thus other SO users will be able to refer to this solution works.